# Docker image hierarchy increases layer size?

Tags: image, docker, dockerfile

In a scenario where a image extends from another image and so on, will this behavior increase the size of a custom image adding bigger layers?

For example:
The image cbelleza/springboot-maven-s2i extends from alpine image, in this case the size of all dependencies would it be (115MB + 3.97MB) ?

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                      TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
cbelleza/springboot-maven-s2i   latest              3b92af74af2d        28 minutes ago      115MB
alpine                          latest              7328f6f8b418        2 weeks ago         3.97MB
```

Having a shared parent image that is referenced in multiple children images, does it reduce the size of those children images, or is better having a single image with all dependencies and commands included inside (apk, .gz, tar, etc)?

Comment: In general, common layers should only be cached once.

Comment: but do you think the size is smaller keeping everything inside a single image or splitting in many images by purposes?

Comment: Think an image as a layer plus metadata. Think layers as a tree of dependencies. The size of an image is the sum of its pointed layer plus each ancestor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q. In a scenario where a image extends from another image and so on, will this behavior increase the size of a custom image adding bigger layers?

Each layer apport a differential amount of data, and does not repeat the previous ones.

Think an image as a layer plus metadata. Think layers as a tree of dependencies. The size of an image is the sum of its pointed layer plus each ancestor.

Let's say:

```
[layer A, image alpine] -> [layer B, no image] .-> [layer C, image app 1]
                                               |
                                                -> [layer D, image app 2]
```

Size of `image app1 = size(C) + size(B) + size(A)`

Size of `image app2 = size(D) + size(B) + size(A)`

> Q. In this case, the size of all dependencies would it be (115MB + 3.97MB)?

Yes, but the real size in the disk will be much smaller due to they share layers.

> Q. Having a shared parent image that is referenced in multiple children images, does it reduce the size of those children images, or is better having a single image with all dependencies and commands included inside (apk, .gz, tar, etc)?

You can have 1 base image of 1GB and 100 children images of 1MB, the total disk space will be (roughly) = 1GB + 100*1MB ~= 2GB. And **not** 1GB + 100*(1MB + 1GB).
However, the size of each child image is still 1GB + 1MB.

The same concept is applied in a docker registry, which will reuse any previously pushed layer.

Some docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/)

Comment: So, in the end is better having parent images than a single (like a monolithic), because they share the common layers between them

Comment: But is the same to put N files in N layers versus N files in a single layer. The sum is the same.

Comment: You're welcome! BTW I've played a lot with layers so I reached that outcomes.